# Does filter operation in Polars maintain the original row order

Tags: python, python-polars

May be a quick question: if I have a dataframe `df` which is sorted on say column `a` and if I do a filter operations on it such as `df2 = df.filter((pl.col("b") > 2) & (pl.col("b") < 5)`, is df2 sorted on `a` as well or more strictly, does rows in `df2` have the same relatively order as they were before in `df`?

I have done some experimentations and it seems like the original orders are maintained after `filter`, but not sure if it is indeed the case and API doc does not have some statements about that.

Maybe a follow-up question is what kind of operations do we expect the row orders maintained/preserved and what not?

Comment: Any operation that has a `maintain_order=` parameter that defaults to `False` can change the order e.g. `.groupby`, `.unique`, `.upsample`

Comment: Good to know. That means anything without ```maintain_order=``` will not alter the order? Just to confirm.

Comment: That is how I understand things, though I've not seen this documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does preserve the order, both for [`LazyFrame`s](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.filter.html) and [`DataFrame`s](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.filter.html), as it suggests in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can test this using the `is_sorted` method of a Series object.

For example:

```
df=pl.DataFrame({'a':[x for x in range(100)], 'b':[x for x in range(100, 0, -1)]})
df.get_column('a').is_sorted()
# True
df.get_column('b').is_sorted()
# False
df.filter(pl.col('b')>20).get_column('a').is_sorted()
# True
```

Comment: Sure, I tested out a bit and empirical results showed that order is preserved after filter operation. But just would like to see if that is a guarantee implemented in the logic.